# Framebuffer objects with single channel texture attachment? (Color attachment)

Tags: opengl

I would like the fragment-shader to output a single byte value. Rendered to a one-channel texture attached to a framebuffer object. I have only ever used the default fragment shader to output a vec4 for color. Is this possible? If I initialized the texture bound to the fbo as color attachment like this:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_R8, width, height, 0, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
```

If so, would I change the fragment shaders out variable from:

out vec4 color

to:

out int color?

(I am trying to render a height map)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, your render target is not an integer texture; it's a normalized integer format, which counts as a float. So the corresponding output variable from your shader should be a floating-point type.

But you can use a `vec4` if you like; any components that are not part of the render target will be discarded.

Comment: So, GL_R8 is an acceptable format for a fbo color attachement? from https://open.gl/framebuffers : "Since this is the image for the color buffer, the format and internalformat parameters are a bit more restricted. The format parameter will typically be limited to either GL_RGB or GL_RGBA and the internalformat to the color formats."

Comment: I could use RGB, but i only need the red (or one channel). So it would be a waste to allocate for 3 channels. If you catch my thinking. @Nicol Bolas

Comment: @Dahl: The [last three parameters are irrelevant for the format of the texture](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Pixel_Transfer#Pixel_transfer_arguments) (and that tutorial is kind of bad for even bringing it up in this context). The only parameter that matters here is the internal format. And `GL_R8` is one of "the color formats".